# Properties of function - convexity and existing gradient

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function whose gradient $\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)$
exists at every point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and satisfies the condition
\begin{equation*}
    \exists \ L>0 \text{  }\text{ } \forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n \text{  }\text{ } \lVert \nabla f(x_1)-\nabla f(x_2)\rVert \leq L\lVert x_1-x_2\rVert.
\end{equation*}
Prove that
\begin{equation*}
    \forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n \text{  }\text{ } \lVert \nabla f(x_1)-\nabla f(x_2)\rVert^2 \leq L \langle \nabla f(x_1)-\nabla f(x_2), x_1-x_2\rangle.
\end{equation*}

Solution:

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(x_1)-\langle \nabla f(x_1),x-x_1\rangle.$

How to show that $g$ has the same properties as $f$? I proved the inequality, but what with convexity and existing gradient?

Comment: Note that $g$ is $f$ (which is convex and differentiable) minus a term that is linear in $x$.

Comment: Google Baillon-Haddad Theorem. E.g., in the book by Bauschke-Combettes.